# how to get value in comma separated value db field in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

My table as below:

```
id  | user_ids
---------------
1     1,2,3
2     9,11,20
3     21,20,11
```

I need the result as:

```
user_ids
--------
1
2 
3
9
```

how to get seperate the `user_ids` field

Comment: Have u tried something?

Comment: can any one tell me is this the correct way to store values in db?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$str = '1,2,3,4'; //pass your user_ids here.

$arr = explode(',',$str);
foreach($arr as $num)
{
    echo $num."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code you posted? It's usually preffered to give some explenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$user_ids = '1,2,3';
$user_idsArray = explode(',', $user_ids);
for($i = 0; $i < count($user_idsArray); $i++)
{
    $item = array('user_ids' => $user_idsArray[$i]);
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $item);
}
```